# how to save a list object in R

Tags: r, analysis

I did coxph for my data and get result like this:

```
> z
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Years, Event) ~ y, data = x)


    coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z   p
y 0.0714      1.07    0.288 0.248 0.8


Likelihood ratio test=0.06  on 1 df, p=0.804  n= 65, number of events= 49
```

I just want to save

```
y 0.0714      1.07    0.288 0.248 0.8
```

into a file. Because I do permutation and generate 1000 z.

I want to save them into a text file like this:

```
fin -0.3794 0.684 0.1914 -1.983 0.0470
age -0.0574 0.944 0.0220 -2.611 0.0090
race 0.3139 1.369 0.3080 1.019 0.3100
wexp -0.1498 0.861 0.2122 -0.706 0.4800
mar -0.4337 0.648 0.3819 -1.136 0.2600
paro -0.0849 0.919 0.1958 -0.434 0.6600
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficients are easily accessed by

```
summary(z)[['coefficients']]
```

and the confidence interval information by

```
summary(z)[['conf.int']]
```

To find out what the components of a `summary.coxph` object

```
str(summary(z))
```

My advice would be to create a list of your permutations

```
data_list <- list(data_1, ...., data_1000)
```

Then call

```
lots_models <- lapply(data_list, coxph, formula = Surv(Years, Event) ~ y)
```

Which creates a list of models

You can create the summaries by

```
lots_summaries <- lapply(lots_models, summary)
```

Extract the coefficients

```
all_coefficients <- lapply(lots_summaries, '[[', 'coefficients')
all_conf.int     <- lapply(lots_summaries, '[[', 'conf.int')
```

Add a permutation id column (if you want)

```
all_coefs_id <- lapply(seq_along(data_list), 
   function(i) cbind(all_coefficients[[i]],i))
all_ci_id <- lapply(seq_along(data_list), 
   function(i) cbind(all_conf.int[[i]],i))
```

Then combine into a data.frame

```
all_coefs_df <- do.call(rbind, all_coefs_id)
all_ci_df <- do.call(rbind, all_ci_id)
```

Which you than then save as a text file

Comment: Thanks so much.
And if I want to save the <pre>
  exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
y     1.074     0.9311    0.6105     1.889
</pre>
as well. How can I save it.

Comment: I mean when I use summary(z), i can get two info: coef exp(coef) se(coef) z Pr(>|z|) y 0.07137 1.07398 0.28817 0.248 0.804 and exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95 y 1.074 0.9311 0.6105 1.889 summary(z)[['coefficients']] can save the first one, but I also want to save the second one. Thanks!

Comment: omg, thanks a lot. BUt can i ask where do you find the name for the data. I don't how to find it. I checked ?coxph but dont have any findings.